# keyboard application crashed after button pressed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, custom-keyboard

I am trying to replace some strings which pickup from proxy, and I already run this code, give me no error. but actually it just doesn't work.
I don't know where I am doing wrong.
actually in simulator, the interface can be displayed, but when I click the button, caused crash.

OS Platform: Mac OS 12.5.1

Xcode version: Version 13.4.1

Swift Version: Swift 5

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox
import SwiftUI

  class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    var Yuanyin:String!
    var bianyuanyin:String!
    var bufferletters:Substring!
    private var proxy: UITextDocumentProxy {
        return textDocumentProxy
    }

 @IBAction func keypressed(sender: UIButton) {

       // insert text
       let character = sender.titleLabel!.text!
       proxy.insertText(character)
       
       // check shiftStatus
       if shiftStatus == 1 {
        shiftbuttonpressed(self.ShiftButton)
        }
 
        // replace letters with tones

        let Str3 = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput
        let Last3Letter = Str3!.suffix(3)
        let Str2 = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput
        let Last2Letter = Str2!.suffix(2)
        let Str1 = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput
        let LastLetter = Str1!.suffix(1)
         if (LastLetter.range(of: "ɑ", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            deleteletters = 1
            replaceletters()
            bianyuanyin = "ɑ"
            bufferletters = LastLetter
        }
        
        //replace lastletter // uppercased

        if (Last2Letter.range(of: "UN", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            deleteletters = 2
            replaceletters()
            bianyuanyin = "U"
            bufferletters = Last2Letter
        }
```

```
 func replaceletters(){
           let Yuanyin = bianyuanyin
           let Bianxing1 = (Yuanyin ?? "") + "\u{0304}"
           let Bianxing2 = (Yuanyin ?? "") + "\u{0301}"
           let Bianxing3 = (Yuanyin ?? "") + "\u{030C}"
           let Bianxing4 = (Yuanyin ?? "") + "\u{0300}"
            Tone1Button.titleLabel?.text = bufferletters.replacingOccurrences(of: (Yuanyin ?? ""), with: Bianxing1)
            Tone2Button.titleLabel?.text = bufferletters.replacingOccurrences(of: (Yuanyin ?? ""), with: Bianxing2)
            Tone3Button.titleLabel?.text = bufferletters.replacingOccurrences(of: (Yuanyin ?? ""), with: Bianxing3)
            Tone4Button.titleLabel?.text = bufferletters.replacingOccurrences(of: (Yuanyin ?? ""), with: Bianxing4)
            Tone1Button.setTitle(Tone1Button.titleLabel?.text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            Tone2Button.setTitle(Tone2Button.titleLabel?.text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            Tone3Button.setTitle(Tone3Button.titleLabel?.text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            Tone4Button.setTitle(Tone4Button.titleLabel?.text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
       }
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, I would suggest moving the business logic in your view controller into a view model class. From there, you can write unit tests against your methods and once you have them doing what you want, drop the view model into your view controller and wire it up that way.

Comment: Additionally, I see a bunch of force unwraps in our code. You should use if-lets or guards instead of myVar!.doSomething.